# After connecting to remote database, migrating gives error: Errno61, Connection Refused

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I recently started using sql and connected to an remote sql server. I can run queries on it in python shell and get correct results. However, when I run 
`manage.py runserver`

It tells me that there I need to migrate, however when I migrate I get an error saying:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '*host*' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")
```

What should I do to fix this error.

setting.py database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '*name*',
        'USER': '*user*',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': '*host*',
        'PORT': '****',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

full error list here:

```
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'masspike.ctqk1lhawxna.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/lwyss/PycharmProjects/NewWebsite/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
```

Comment: This looks like a firewall issue.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So how could I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the [MySQLConnector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'masspike.ctqk1lhawxna.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)"

So this is a **networking** problem in which your application is unable to establish a TCP connection to your database. Maybe because of a lack of configuration on your RDS instance? wrong hostname? wrong port? firewall (as mentioned by @Willem van Onsem)? Maybe the [Amazon AWS guide on connecting to their database service helps you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html)

In any case it has nothing to do with your program code, apart from the *connection string* if its wrong.

Comment: I am pretty sure the hostname and port are correct because I can connect to the server in terminal. Perhaps I have a firewall problem. Thank you for the quick answer!